# Record Call on Android 6+

Tags: android, audio-recording, phone-call

i have an Call Recorder that worked fine on Android 5 but is not working on android 6+, the Audio Recorder will not intialize when i use Audio Source 4 (= call) but if i use audio source 1 (=mic) it is intializing and recording.

Does anyone know how to get it work on android 6+? is there any example of Call recorder for android 6+?

thank you, ilan

Answer (score 0):

At first check do you request runtime permissions to record:

```
 int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission to record denied");
        }
```

And additional information (problems and solutions) you can find [here](https://bitbucket.org/copluk/acr/issues/593/kb-android-6-call-recording-issues-merged)

Comment: thank you for your answer but i set targetsdk = 19 in manifest so i dont have to ask for permissions. i will check also the link you post maybe i will find a solution. i managed to record on some android 6 devices by putting the audio source to MIC but on galaxy s5 it did not helped. on galaxy s7 it worked.